# Handling transient entity in delete processing. entity not be deleted [Solve]

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, jpa

My problem is when i use this code to remove a `Ship` entity i get this message

> 08-Mar-2017 13:01:36.504 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultDeleteEventListener.deleteTransientEntity HHH000114: Handling transient entity in delete processing

However after commit, my entity still exists in the database

I use

    `Spring 4.2.1.RELEASE
    Hibernate 4.3.5.Final
    Mysql 5.1.30`

### Code :

**Ship :**

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"player", "game", "version"})
@Entity
@Table( name = "ship_tbl",
    uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint( columnNames = { "ship_name" , "game_id"}, name = "UK_ship_player") } )
public class Ship extends AbstractShip {

private Player player;
private Game game;
private Long version;

@Version
@Column(name = "ship_version")
public Long getVersion() {
    return version;
}

public void setVersion(Long version) {
    this.version = version;
}

@Override
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "ship_id")
public Long getId() {
    return super.getId();
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Player.class)
@JoinColumn(name="player_id", nullable = false)
public Player getPlayer() {
    return player;
}

@Override
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, targetEntity = Cargo.class)
@JoinColumn(name="cargo_id", nullable = false)
public AbstractCargo getCargo() {
    return super.getCargo();
}

@Override
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, targetEntity = ShipWay.class)
@JoinColumn(name="shipway_id", nullable = false)
public AbstractShipWay getShipWay() {
    return super.getShipWay();
}

@Override
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = ShipKind.class)
@JoinColumn(name="shipkind_id", nullable = false)
public AbstractShipKind getShipKind() {
    return super.getShipKind();
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Game.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "game_id", nullable = false)
public Game getGame() {
    return game;
}

public void setGame(Game game) {
    this.game = game;
}

@Override
@Column(name = "ship_name", nullable = false)
public String getName() {
    return super.getName();
}

public void setPlayer(Player player) {
    this.player = player;
}

public Ship(Long id, String name, AbstractCargo cargo, AbstractShipKind shipKind, AbstractShipWay shipWay, Player player, Game game) {
    super(id, name, cargo, shipKind, shipWay);
    this.player = player;
    this.game = game;
}

public Ship(String name, AbstractCargo cargo, AbstractShipKind shipKind,AbstractShipWay shipWay) {
    this(null, name, cargo, shipKind, shipWay,null,null);
}

public Ship() {
    this(null,null,null,null);
}

}
```

**Dao**

This one remove the ship :

```
private void removeShip(Session session, Ship ship) {
    Ship s = new Ship();
    s.setId(ship.getId());
    session.delete(s);
}
```

Remove the ship and add to the player is gold for the ship :

```
private void sellShip(Session session, Player player, Ship ship) throws ShipNotExistsException {
    removeShip(session, ship);
    updatePlayerGold(session, player, ship.getShipKind().sellShipAmount());
}
```

Do the transaction plus return int error :

```
@Override
public int sellShip(Player player, Ship ship) {
    int error;
    Session session = null;
    Transaction transaction = null;

    try{
        session = openSession();
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        transaction.setTimeout(5);

        sellShip(session, player, ship);

        transaction.commit();

        error = Response.ERROR_NONE_ERRORS;
    }catch(RuntimeException e) {
        if(e instanceof ShipNotExistsException) {
            error = Response.ERROR_SHIP_NOT_EXISTS_OR_MATCH;
        } else {
            e.printStackTrace();
            //TODO add else if stament and else insetent this
            //already in transtaction
            error = Response.ERROR_ALREADY_IN_TRANSACTION;
        }

        //if(!(e instanceof LockAcquisitionException)) {
        try {
            transaction.rollback();
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            re.printStackTrace();
        }
        //}
        //throw e;
    }finally{
        if(session!=null){
            session.close();
        }
    }
    return error;
}
```

I am on this problem 3 hours and i will grateful for any help or explanation !

Thank you for reding.

### Solution :

as @Maciej Kowalski said in hes answer. i change the new Ship(), by merge.

more then, i will forget to tell you about the `Player` entity as show here :

```
public class Player extends AbstractPlayer {
...
@Override
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, targetEntity = Ship.class, mappedBy = "player")
public Set<AbstractShip> getShips() {
    return super.getShips();
}
...
}
```

well the `one-to-many` is the problem when exsits 'fetch = FetchType.EAGER'

solve one from this two option :

1. change fetch to "lazy", as i didn't do.
2. add this before delete `managedShip.getPlayer().getShips().remove(managedShip);` equal to `parentEntity.collection.remove(childEntity)` as i do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your delete method you should perform a merge before performing the delete operation. Im not sure why you create a new instance of Ship class, i think that can be omitted:

```
private void removeShip(Session session, Ship ship) {
    Ship managedShip = session.merge(ship);
    session.delete(managedShip);
}
```

Before you remove an entity you have to make sure it is managed by the persistence provider.

Comment: Thank you for your anwer. after i do what you anwer and more somthing it work !

Comment: Great. Glad i could help

Comment: If i merge the Ship then it's added to the DB, then I delete the managedShip so overall I did nothing. Can't I get the managed object without merge?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change order of statement in your method as below:

```
private void sellShip(Session session, Player player, Ship ship) throws ShipNotExistsException {
    updatePlayerGold(session, player, ship.getShipKind().sellShipAmount());
    removeShip(session, ship);
}
```